# Ruby on Rails graphics

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Would like to know what is the best framework/library for rich server side graphics on Ruby on Rails.

Comment: Asking for superlatives like *best* or *worst* usually leads to unnecessary flame wars. It would be nicer if you explained your specific use case for graphics so that people have a better chance of giving you a useful answer rather than mindlessly cheering for their favorite framework/library.

Answer (score 2):

Would [**RMagick**](http://rmagick.rubyforge.org/) cut it? Almost every project involving server side image generation uses it.

Answer (score 2):

http://ruby-toolbox.com/categories/graphing.html lists the most popular